# Footer works with Angular <router-outlet>

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm creating a website with Angular2+, and basically in the main file there are 3 "sections": header, content, footer.

The goal is to make the header and the footer behave like expected, which is: header always on top, but when I scroll, it disappear. Content is 100vh - header size - footer size. And footer is always at the bottom, so if there's nothing in the content, the footer is at the bottom, and when there are stuffs that can't be shown without scrolling, the footer disappear and goes to the bottom of the page.

Well, that's working ONLY IF the content is directly put in the div content. If the content is from another component, and that comes from the  tag inside the div content, the page doesn't work as expected, like, the content goes over the footer.

You can see the entire code here: https://github.com/joaocasarin/joaocasarin.github.io

And you can see the website here: https://joaocasarin.github.io

In the homepage everything is okay, because the content is small, there's no need of scrolling.

But if you go to the Skills menu, you will see the problem:

[image: image of the screen with big content getting over the footer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
height: calc(100vh - 80px - 50px);
```

on `.wrapper` in app-skills component.

Add on `.wrapper` in app-skills component:

```
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0 0 100px;
```

Where "100px" is the choosen height of your footer.

With height on .wrapper removed:
[image]

**Edited:**
Don't add the styles on `.footer`.

Stackblitz edited: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-discord-ht7hmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fskills%2Fskills.component.css

Comment: the `.wrapper` you're referring to is the one in the skills.component or the app.component?

Comment: I changed the one in the skills.component. And with all your modifications, the skills page extend its background color to the bottom, but the footer is still in the middle

Comment: In the skills component. You have removed the "height: calc(100vh - 80px - 50px);" style on the skills component? It's the main problem.

Comment: Yes I did, with your answer there are 2 results: by only removing the calc height on wrapper, the footer goes to the bottom, but it I remove some of those progress bars and the content becomes small, the footer doesn't stick to the bottom, it floats to the top. And, if I add those changes suggested by you, without content, the footer is at the bottom, but if I add anything that makes me scroll the screen, the footer is in the middle of the content...

Comment: This is the stackblitz for this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-discord-3kmewd

Comment: I edited my response. Don't add the styles on `.footer`. Don't work with your use case.

Stackblitz edited: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-discord-ht7hmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fskills%2Fskills.component.css

Comment: would you know why that horizontal scrolling bar appears if the "content" is bigger than the viewport height?

Comment: I don't know. This is an another question. There are too many styles. Review all your css styles with properties that you know.

Comment: Will you rate me the answer?